# Using where in a list

Tags: haskell

Is there any way to use a `where` expression inside the list syntax? I imagined something like this would work:

```
foo = [i where i = 1]
```

But compilation yields:

> error: parse error on input ‘where’

It's possible to use `let ... in` inside a list:

```
foo = [let i = 1 in i]
```

So I assume that `where` and `let` behave as different syntactic constructs?

I'm aware it's possible to do:

```
foo = [i] where i = 1
```

... but for more complicated lists the distance between the `i` and the `i = 1` is too far for it to be clear - see the context section below and imagine many more test cases, and this `testGroup` itself nested inside a list.

---

**Context**

I ran across this while trying to write a readable testcase:

```
testGroup "toInput"
[
    testProperty "toInput '*'" (forAll others conversionFails)
            where others = arbitrary `suchThat` (\c -> c `notElem` exclChars)
                  conversionFails c = toInput c == Nothing
]
```

The equivalent with `let` just isn't as satisfying to read imo (and, more concretely, when surrounded by other test cases, the `testProperty` not being on the same indentation as them makes it harder to follow).

```
testGroup "toInput"
[
    let others = arbitrary `suchThat` (\c -> c `notElem` exclChars)
        conversionFails c = toInput c == Nothing
    in
        testProperty "toInput '*'" (forAll others conversionFails)
]
```

Comment: A `where` is bound to a syntactical block: https://wiki.haskell.org/Let_vs._Where. So an entire function clause, whereas `let` is more locally scoped.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem Ohhh, I see - that's a shame.

Comment: You might be looking for *list comprehensions*.

Comment: @Davislor 'fraid not, I'm constructing a list with specific single elements, rather than drawing them from another list.

Comment: @hnefatl `[1 | 1==2]` is a list comprehension too.

Comment: In that case, `let xs = [i] where i = 1`.

Comment: @Davislor this only works at GHCi prompt.

Comment: @WillNess Works fine in the context of `main = let xs = [i] where i = 1 in print xs`, but if you have `main = print xs`, you would write `xs = [i] where i = 1`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Like the [Haskell Wiki article says](https://wiki.haskell.org/Let_vs._Where):

> It is important to know that `let ... in ...` is an expression, that is, it can be written **wherever expressions are allowed**. In contrast, `where`
>   is bound to a **surrounding syntactic construct**, like the pattern matching line of a function definition.

So in short, `where` is bound to the clause of a function declaration, whereas `let` is more locally scoped in an expression. If you write `where`, it is visible for the entire clause, like:

```
f a | a > 0 = g b b
    | otherwise = b
    where b = g a a
```

so here the `where` is visible for the two guards, a `let` is more locally scoped. If you write `let y = f x in y * y`, then that `y` is only *visible* in the `in ...` part. For example we can write:

```
Prelude> let a = 4 in (let a = 2 in a) + a
6
```

So here the inner `a` is `2` whereas the outer is `4`. This might end up to be very confusing. If we would define variables with the same name in a `where` clause, this would result in name conflicts.

In case your code sample is a single function, you can of course move this out of the list definition, like:

```
foo exclChars = 
  testGroup "toInput" [testProperty "toInput '*'" (forAll others conversionFails)]
  where others = arbitrary `suchThat` (`notElem` exclChars)
        conversionFails = isNothing . toInput
```

Comment: `foo` should only have one argument, `exclChars`, no? Also, you could replace `conversionFails` with `Data.Maybe.isNothing . toInput`.

Comment: @chepner: correct. I did not read the semantics of the code in the question. It was more a "syntax" transformation.

Answer (score 2):

`[1 | 1==2]` is a list comprehension too. `1==2` is a Boolean *expression*.

In your example `foo = [let i = 1 in i]`, the `let i = 1 in i` is an expression as well.

Indeed `where` and `let` are different. `let` forms an expression, but `where` does not - it is a part of a definition (`a = b where ...`).

Difference is, a variable defined by `where` can be used in the definition's *guards*, whereas `let` goes on the right hand side of the `=` sign.

To your question, just move `]` before the `where`, and it will become part of the definition where it appears.

Answer (score 1):

You might be looking forward to using list comprehensions. In list comprehensions, you could use `|` which means *such that*, and you can say `[ i | i <- [1] ]`. So, you might use them as follows: `[ ... | others <- [suchThat arbitrary (\c -> notElem c exclChars)]` in your example.

Comment: But this has nothing to do with list comprehension. Here a singleton list is constructed.

Comment: You can create singleton lists using list comprehensions by giving singleton generators and use them as where clauses.

Comment: @WillNess: yes, but nowhere in the question is there a condition that decides whether or not to add an element. It simply wrappes a result into a singleton-list. It is  quite strange to use a concept that simply is orthogonal on the task.

Answer (score 1):

I'm unsure about why do you want this specific list comprehension, but this works, and you can try it in GHCi:

```
> [ i | let i=1 ]
[1]
```

You can't instead use `where` in a list comprehension to this effect.